# Error trigger jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este `div` ,por defecto al pasar el mouse por encima de él se mueve con `CSS3`, ahora con `jquery` intento que cada `1000ms`, se envié un lanzar como si estuvieran pasando el `mouse`, con motivo de que se mueva constantemente cada 1 segundo(1000ms)

El problema es que no me funciona y no entiendo que está mal.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ogar.pw/assets/css/anim.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(function() {
     $('#play-btn').trigger('mouseover');
     $('.hvr-wobble-horizontal').trigger('mouseover');
      }, 1000);

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green; position: absolute;" class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" id="play-btn"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es adicionar una clase Active, y removerla cada intervalo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ogar.pw/assets/css/anim.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
 .active {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
 }

 @keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
   transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
   transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
   transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
   transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
 }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
   
   
   setTimeout(function(){
    $('#play-btn').removeClass('active');
   }, 1000)

   $('#play-btn').addClass('active');
   
  }, 2000);


 });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green; position: absolute;" class="hvr-wobble-horizontal" id="play-btn"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes simular el evento `mouseover` debido a que no es un evento de confianza.

> Most **untrusted events will not trigger default actions**, with the
>   exception of the click event. This event always triggers the default
>   action, even if the isTrusted attribute is false (this behavior is
>   retained for backward-compatibility). All other **untrusted events
>   behave as if the preventDefault() method** had been called on that
>   event.

La solución más sencilla es crear una clase [css](/questions/tagged/css) que dispare la animación/transición y añadirla/quitarla en cada iteración.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const animate = () => {
  setTimeout(() => $('#box').addClass('active'), 1000);
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#box').removeClass('active');
    animate();
  }, 2000);
};

animate();
```

```css
#box {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, turquoise, gold);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  height: 150px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  width: 150px;
}

#box.active {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```